# How to grant access to user from other Domain

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are doing some development that involves BigQuery. One of our consultants does not have an account and does not have an email in our domain. Is there a way of granting him access?

Cheers,
Cris

Comment: If his domain is configured with Gsuite or his email address is from gmail.com , then you can grant him access from IAM console(https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)

make sure you are granting right permission/role while adding user.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. His mail is not configured with Gsuite and its not a gmail. Any ideas? We could create an email in our domain but for future knowledge if there are other ways would be good to know.

Comment: No, there is no other way a google uses SSO for all of the applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google cloud only accept a google account as a valid account, be it a google group, a gsuite account or a service account.

The best use case would be to generate a service account, and let him use this account with the gcloud sdk using the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable.

In the case he would not be able to use the service account or if the product is not really friendly in the gcloud cli (I don't know much about bigquery), you could create a personnal account in your organization for him to used, or you could authorized his personal gmail account (check if 2fa is activated... We never know)...